# Mysql (doctrine) - count inner join having count > X

Tags: mysql, sql, join, doctrine

I have SQL to count products with specific properties. I am using it in the products filter. SQL is very long, but here is the primary part:

```
SELECT COUNT(products.id) as products_count, property_items.description, property_items.id as id
FROM property_items
INNER JOIN product_properties ON property_items.id = product_properties.property_item_id
INNER JOIN products ON product_properties.product_id
INNER JOIN product_properties pp ON products.id = pp.product_id AND (pp.property_item_id IN ($ids))
GROUP BY property_items.id
HAVING COUNT(pp.id) >= $countIds
```

This works perfectly when I have only the one element in `$ids`, but when i choose one more, the result is bad. It looks like the sql returns count of all products with any property from `$ids`, but I need to count only products that contains all properties.

First get all available properties. On each property join products that contains this property and go back to all properties of this product to check, if product contains already checked properties too. Or it is bad idea? I need to keep primary table (FROM table) as `property_items`.

I need to get result in this format:

```
=============================
id|description|products_count
=============================
1 |lorem ipsum|10
-----------------------------
2 |dolore sit |2
```

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT products.id) as cnt

Comment: This does not works :/ Any change, I mean the problem is in grouping ..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the product ids that have all the properties by doing:

```
SELECT pp.property_id
FROM property_items pi INNER JOIN
     product_properties pp
     ON pi.id = pp.property_item_id INNER JOIN
     products p
     ON pp.product_id = p.id
WHERE pp.property_item_id IN ($ids)
GROUP BY pp.property_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pp.property_item_id) = $countIds  -- has all of them
```

Note that I rationalized the joins.  I think your simplification of the query wasn't quite right.  I also added table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.

If you want the count of such products, use a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT pp.property_id
      FROM property_items pi INNER JOIN
           product_properties pp
           ON pi.id = pp.property_item_id INNER JOIN
           products p
           ON pp.product_id = p.id
      WHERE find_in_set(pp.property_item_id, $ids)
      GROUP BY pp.property_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pp.property_item_id) = $countIds  -- has all of them
     ) ;
```

Your problem is probably because of this line:

```
      WHERE pp.property_item_id IN ($ids)
```

If you are passing `$ids` as a comma-separated string, then your query will not work.  Note the replacement above.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly for "one property", but i need different result. Edited answer: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54197392/revisions

Comment: @Mabezdek . . . That is probably because of how you are passing in the `$ids`.  Your question doesn't explain that, but it is probably where the problem lies.

Comment: when I use your first example, I get multiple rows - duplicates. I need to get unique rows by property_id, and for each row count of products.

Comment: @Mabezdek . . . The aggregation should be by `pp.property_id`.  All those "p"s get confusing.